# Endpoint Server GraphQL (overblog-GraphQLBundle) Not support Method POST

Tags: graphql, symfony4

For 3 Days, my project which worked perfectly locally, once put on the production server.
GraphQl requests are a failure with the error "[Error: Network error: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<']" and after log analysis it is a 404 error because the route was not found.

After investigation via the GraphQl Atlair client for chrome by changing the method to GET to make my GrasphQl requests, the error everything works.

my question is how to work the POST method?

I really need to use the METHOD POST for mutations
Thanks everyone
Very cordially

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a trailing slash to your GraphQL endpoint URL.

Related issue (solved): https://github.com/overblog/GraphQLBundle/issues/669